# Google API's to identify road blockage/Closed signs

Tags: google-maps, real-time, traffic

How can Identify real-time traffic blockage from one point to another. How can I access real-time information to generate alerts.

[Sample Blockage sign, how to identify that road is blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYbfx.jpg)
[Sample Warning alerts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYbfx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Google Routes](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/routes/), It provides routes between points A and B and in the response Json returns a warnings tag that should give you what you need.

Comment: Do you mean it returns warnings but they are not JSON formatted or they aren’t present? It might help a bit to get a use case. Is this system for during travel or to alert someone that their planned journey might take longer than normal?

Comment: Also where are you based?

Comment: I mean to say that How can I get warning alerts that are displayed in google Maps.